# Dash / Plotly draw vrect in graph or change drawn rectangle's height

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm currently building a time series labeling tool in Dash for which I'm utilizing the plotly inbuild `drawrect` function in the figure like this:

```
fig.update_layout(dragmode='drawrect', newshape={
        "drawdirection": "vertical",
        "layer": "below",
        "fillcolor": "green",
        "opacity": 0.25,
        "line": {
            "width": 0
        }
    })
```

this is perfect with one flaw, the drawn rectangles are only as high as the current zoom and if you zoom out it doesn't fill the whole screen vertically anymore.
I've seen that plotly has the ability to draw `vrects` which are exaclty what I want but I don't see how can draw them with the mouse. Is there a way I can specify the height or a way to change the height to be infinite as soon as someone draws a rect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**:

To generate an infinitely high rectangle upon drawing, you can trigger a callback when drawing a regular rectangle, capture its X-coordinates, delete the layout to remove that rectangle, then draw a `vrect` that will have the same x-coordinates but will be infinitely high. Here is an example:

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id="sensor-graph",
        config={
            'modeBarButtonsToAdd': [
                "drawrect",
                "eraseshape"
            ]
        },
    ),
])

@app.callback(
    [
        Output('sensor-graph', 'figure')
    ],
    Input("sensor-graph", "relayoutData"),
    [State('sensor-graph', 'figure')],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def on_new_annotation(relayout_data, fig):
    figu = go.Figure(fig)
    # Check if the changed layout in the graph is a drawn shape
    if fig is not None and "shapes" in relayout_data:
        # Remove the original rectangle
        figu.layout = {}
        # Add an infinitely high rectangle, using the original rectangle's x-coords
        figu.add_vrect(x0=relayout_data["shapes"][0]["x0"], x1=relayout_data["shapes"][0]["x1"])
    return [figu]
```

**Original answer**:
After drawing a rectangle, you can click on it's actual perimeter and it's vertices become drag-able. This way, when you zoom out, you can resize the rectangle's height.

Here is an example of changing it's height using the drag functionality:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't specify enough what exactly I want, I don't want to just change the height but I want the rectangles to have infinite height s.t. I don't see the top or the bottom with any zoom

Comment: Ah ok, Ive edited the answer for infinitely high rectangles